# How do i make a specific pattern for my html input

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to make a custom pattern for my html input but have no idea how to do so!

The pattern I want: ABC-A0-01

So basically the first part has uppercase alphabets only, second part has uppercase with numeric values, and the last part is numeric only and is separated by a '-'

```
<input type="text" class="form-control txtsize" id="equi" placeholder="Insert equipment name e.g ABC-A0-12" data-ng-model="equipmentToAdd">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) attribute with a RegEx such as this: `pattern="[A-Z]{3}[-][A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[-][0-9]{2}"`.

Try inputting an invalid value, and hit submit. The browser will give an error with the message from `title` property.

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" class="form-control txtsize" id="equi" placeholder="Insert equipment name e.g ABC-A0-12" data-ng-model="equipmentToAdd" pattern="[A-Z]{3}[-][A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}[-][0-9]{2}" title="Insert equipment name e.g ABC-A0-12">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```